# Firebase updateChildValues in iOS, what's more optimized?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I work on an iPhone app (Swift 4), I do some updates on my database at few nodes at the same time.

Both following methods work but I'm wondering what's the most "clean" one ?

Way 1 :

```
 let idNotification = BaseViewController.database.child("notifications").childByAutoId().key
        BaseViewController.database.child("notifications").child(idNotification).updateChildValues(["content" : "some content"])
        BaseViewController.database.child("users").child(userID).child("notifications").updateChildValues(["something" : true])
```

Way 2 :

```
    let idNotification = BaseViewController.database.child("notifications").childByAutoId().key
    let createNotif = ["content" : "some content"]
    let notifToUser = ["something" : true]
    BaseViewController.database.updateChildValues(["/notifications/\(idNotification)" : createNotif, "/users/\(userID)/notifications" : notifToUser])
```

And if that makes any difference in case of crash ? With the first one, if one of the two update request fail the other one will not be impacted. What happens with method 2 if there is a fail just for one of the two ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet send multiple write operations to the database (one for each call to `updateChildValues`). The second snippet sends exactly one write operation.

Both are completely valid, and either could be what you want. For example, if there's no relation between the two updates, then it makes sense to send them separately. But if the updates are related, it makes more sense to send them in one go, since that allows the security rules of your database to allow/reject them as one write operation.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i wanted to know :)